# Existing asp.net project no new controller function is working, showing 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on existing asp.net website and I get the code from client server where the code was hosted. I was able to run the project in my local pc but when I try to add new controller function then it just show http 404.
![enter image description here][1]

For example in AccountController.cs there was a existing login function

```
    // GET: /Account/Login

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated == true){
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            Session.Abandon();
        }
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Then I copied this function and created a new one like below and also duplicated the view file and renamed

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/AaLogin
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult AaLogin(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            Session.Abandon();
        }
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
        routes.MapRoute(
            "AaLogin", // Route name
            "Account/AaLogin", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Account",
                action = "AaLogin",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ViewListingNoAuth",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Listing", action = "PublicView"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "socialMediaHooks",
            url: "externalService/uploadFlyerToSocialMedia/{id}/{sName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

But it still doesn't work when I browse /Account/AaLogin... any body can help me in this or any resource so I can understand.

If anyone can give me a idea whats happening I would be very happy.

Comment: 404 means its not able to identify the resource. How is your routing defined? Is the new functions under AccountController as well?

Comment: @Kar Yes no new function under account controller is working. But old ones are working just fine.

Comment: Post your routing config

Comment: @Kar I updated the question with the Route config code. Let me know if anything more needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few troubleshooting steps you can try:

1. Observe the call in Fiddler.  Is the call being fired?  If so, does it match what you are expecting?
2. Install [RouteDebugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) (using NuGet) and enable it. This is a great tool to help you see what's going on with your routes.  It will tell you which routing rules are being hit.

P.S. You may want to use one of the "asp.net-mvc" tags for similiar questions.

Comment: Going to have a look as you advice and will let post my findings.

Comment: Looks like its routing accurately, for /Account/Login its showing the view but for /Account/AaLogin showing 404...same error./////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                                         Route Data Key Value
controller Account 
action AaLogin                                                                                       Thats what routedebbuger showing.

Answer (score 0):

Some just changing the route rule order can solve the problem. i had to do it one time to get my application find the route. Try to change the route order in your `Global.asax.cs` file. Put the login route before the default route. sometime it could be the problem !

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer just for the reason that it might help other begginer people. When I was working on the above problem I was almost a begginer in asp.net. But later on I found the reason for it but forgot to update the result. Problem was that client sent me the already builded version not the source code. Later on I got the full source code and was able to make modifications.